# Unable to open camera service in WebRTC Video calling

Tags: java, android, video

I am developing an Android application for text chat, voice and video call using this link [click here](https://github.com/nubomedia-vtt/nubo-test). All the things are working fine except rendering my own video. Due to this, opponent is unable to see my video on his/her device.

Following is the logcat detail

```
E/VideoCapturerAndroid: VideoCapturerAndroid: Camera.open failed, retrying
E/VideoCapturerAndroid: VideoCapturerAndroid: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
E/VideoCapturerAndroid: VideoCapturerAndroid: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
                                                                           at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:352)
                                                                           at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:309)
                                                                           at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid.startCaptureOnCameraThread(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:434)
                                                                           at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid.access$1000(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:65)
                                                                           at org.webrtc.VideoCapturerAndroid$7.run(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:409)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                           01-02 20:29:28.338 25073-15599/com.inn.kurento I/libjingle: (opensslidentity.cc:88): Returning key pair
```

I have tried so many things but still not able to fix the issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one, works for me.**

```
void close(){
        // Uncomment only if you know what you are doing
        try {
            localMediaStream.dispose();
            localMediaStream = null;
            if(videoCapturer!=null){
                videoCapturer.dispose();
            }
            videoCapturer = null;
            videoSource.stop(); //very important
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```